# Unable to download cucumber plugins from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cucumber

Unable to download cucumber plugins from eclipse

[cucumber[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka8aQ.png)

[CucumberEclipseUpdate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DqDy.png)

[natural](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4rjM.png)

[natural8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeEL7.png)

Comment: This isn't a programming question to solve. Report it to https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse/issues .

Answer (score 0):

This is aknown issue for quite a while https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse-update-site-snapshot/issues/1

a workaround is to download the zip from the release page https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse/releasesand install it manually