# installed the natural 0.9 plugin in eclipse the plugin acts as editor for cucumber, issue with natural it show error when syntax is correct as well

Tags: eclipse, cucumber

Mismatched Input Expecting Examples is displayed in Eclipse
When using tags
with Examples
Natural 0.9 is the editor for cucumber
PFA

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please link to the plugin that is used here (this is something that is not built into Eclipse) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: For cucumber tool i installed the natural 0.9 plugin in eclipse
the plugin acts as editor for cucumber issue is with editor it
show error when syntax is correct as well

Comment: Please improve your question by editing it instead of adding comments. If an answer solved your problem, mark it as accepted (up to now you have asked a couple of questions without accepting a single answer), e.g. this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67126309/6505250

Comment: For that matter, have you considered *reporting this as a bug* to the folks behind the Natural plug-in?